# Add data to the next free row at bottom of column list

Tags: vba, excel

pretty basic question but can't seem to get it working. I'm trying to get data from the "origin" cell to copy over to a cell called "destination" in the next *empty* row of a list on the second sheet "Skill Summary". Thanks in advance.

```
Sub btnS()

Dim b As Object
Dim r As Long, c As Long
Dim dest As Range, origin As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim lastrow As Long

With Worksheets("Form")
    Set b = .Buttons(Application.Caller)          'references button
    With b.TopLeftCell                            'returns row and col of button pushed
        r = .row
        c = .Column + 5
    End With

    Set origin = .Cells(r, c)
End With
```

Here is the section that doesn't work

```
    With Worksheets("Skill Summary")
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row + 1
        Set dest = .Cells(lastrow, 2)
    End With

    dest.Value = origin.Value

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use this kind of code.

because as my personal view that "=" is not work to copy data.

```
Sub btnS()
Dim b As Object
Dim r As Long, c As Long
Dim dest As Range, origin As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim lastrow As Long

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a1:a5").Copy
r = Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row + 1

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("a" & Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid Copy & Paste to reduce memory usage and improve the VBA performance

```
 Set b = .Buttons(Application.Caller)          'references button
 With b.TopLeftCell                            'returns row and col of button pushed
    r = .row
    c = .Column
 End With

 Set rng2 = Sheets("Skill Summary").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)

 Sheets("Skill Summary").Range("A" & rng2.Row + 1 & ":A" & rng2.Row + 5).Value = Sheets("Form").Range(Cells(r, c), Cells(r, c+5)).Value
```